# Does having multiple doctypes affect selenium when finding elements?

Tags: python, selenium, doctype

I am trying to automate a website search and selenium keeps giving me errors when clicking on an element saying "NoSuchElementException". This element is in a nested DOCTYPE. Could this affect it?

Comment: This is the xpath that keeps getting the error:

`/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/form/fieldset[1]/div[2]/div[27]/a/span`

Comment: What web site are you testing against? If you cannot reveal it, provide an HTML of the page (or at least of a relevant block on the page) Thanks.

Comment: I figured out it is because it switches to an iframe